# How can I make my Bootstrap 5.3 vertical navbar transition into a offcanvas on smaller screens

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Since Bootstrap 5 have no responsive vertical navbars in their documentation, I decided to build my own one. I made a dashboard with a navbar on the side. As you have read in the title I want to make my vertical navbar to be visible on larger screens and whenever the screen gets smaller I want the navbar transition into offcanvas.

I added the offcanvas class on my navbar, but that makes my navigation disappear. How can I toggle between navbar and offcanvas the most efficient way?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css");

*{
  font-family: Rubik;
}

.container{
    max-width: 1165px !important;
}

.text-underline-hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.text-underline-hover:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#pricing{
  border-radius: 15px !important;
}

.input-group-lg>.btn, .input-group-lg>.form-control, .input-group-lg>.form-select, .input-group-lg>.input-group-text {
  font-size: 1rem !important;
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem !important;
}

.btn{
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #161616 !important;
  border: 0 none !important;
  border-radius: 100px !important;
  padding: 12.5px 40px !important;
}
.btn-lg{

  padding: 12.5px 65px !important;
}
.btn:hover{
  background-color: #332E33 !important;
  outline:0 !important;
}
.btn:focus{
  outline:0 !important;
}
.btn:active {
  background-color: #171715 !important;
  outline:0 !important;
}


/*custom*/
.background{
  background: #CBF3F0 !important;
}
.background2{
  background: #FFF !important;
}

.fw-100{
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}
.fw-200{
  font-weight: 200 !important;
}
.fw-300{
  font-weight: 300 !important;
}
.fw-400{
  font-weight: 400 !important; /* normal */
}
.fw-500{
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
.fw-600{
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.fw-700{
  font-weight: 700 !important; /* bold */
}
.fw-800{
  font-weight: 800 !important;
}
.fw-900{
  font-weight: 900 !important;
}

.fs-05{
  font-size: 0.5rem !important;
}
.fs-06{
  font-size: 0.6rem !important;
}
.fs-07{
  font-size: 0.7rem !important;
}
.fs-08{
  font-size: 0.8rem !important;
}
.fs-09{
  font-size: 0.9rem !important;
}
.fs-10{
  font-size: 1.0rem !important;
}
.fs-11{
  font-size: 1.1rem !important;
}
.fs-12{
  font-size: 1.2rem !important;
}
.fs-13{
  font-size: 1.3rem !important;
}
.fs-14{
  font-size: 1.4rem !important;
}
.fs-15{
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}
.fs-16{
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
}
.fs-17{
  font-size: 1.7rem !important;
}
.fs-18{
  font-size: 1.8rem !important;
}
.fs-19{
  font-size: 1.9rem !important;
}
.fs-20{
  font-size: 2.0rem !important;
}
.fs-21{
  font-size: 2.1rem !important;
}
.fs-22{
  font-size: 2.2rem !important;
}
.fs-23{
  font-size: 2.3rem !important;
}
.fs-24{
  font-size: 2.4rem !important;
}
.fs-25{
  font-size: 2.5rem !important;
}
.fs-26{
  font-size: 2.6rem !important;
}
.fs-27{
  font-size: 2.7rem !important;
}
.fs-28{
  font-size: 2.8rem !important;
}
.fs-29{
  font-size: 2.9rem !important;
}
.fs-30{
  font-size: 3.0rem !important;
}
.fs-31{
  font-size: 3.1rem !important;
}
.fs-32{
  font-size: 3.2rem !important;
}
.fs-33{
  font-size: 3.3rem !important;
}
.fs-34{
  font-size: 3.4rem !important;
}
.fs-35{
  font-size: 3.5rem !important;
}
.fs-36{
  font-size: 3.6rem !important;
}
.fs-37{
  font-size: 3.7rem !important;
}
.fs-38{
  font-size: 3.8rem !important;
}
.fs-39{
  font-size: 3.9rem !important;
}
.fs-40{
  font-size: 4.0rem !important;
}

.br-5{
  border-radius: 5px !important;
}
.br-10{
  border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.br-15{
  border-radius: 15px !important;
}
.br-20{
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
.br-25{
  border-radius: 25px !important;
}
.br-30{
  border-radius: 30px !important;
}
.br-35{
  border-radius: 35px !important;
}
.br-40{
  border-radius: 40px !important;
}
.br-45{
  border-radius: 45px !important;
}
.br-50{
  border-radius: 50px !important;
}

.custom-text-truncate {
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.custom-search {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-search-input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 25px 27.5px;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}
.custom-search-botton {
  position: absolute;
  right: 7.5px; 
  top: 7.5px;
  bottom: 7.5px;
  border: 0;
  background: #161616;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 80px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 1.25rem !important;
}




.btn-toggle-nav a {
  padding: .1875rem .5rem;
  margin-top: .125rem;
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
.btn-toggle-nav a:hover,
.btn-toggle-nav a:focus {
  background-color: #CBF3F0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#navbar{
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding: .1875rem .5rem;
  margin-top: .125rem;
}
#navbar:hover{
  background-color: #CBF3F0 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.sb-active{
  background-color: #CBF3F0 !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Status | Hosting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #F4F4F5;">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 p-0">
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start show" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasExample" aria-labelledby="offcanvasExampleLabel">
                <div class="d-flex" style="height:100vh;">
                    <nav class="bg-light p-2 h-100 w-100">
                        <div class="offcanvas-header ps-2 pe-2">
                            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasExampleLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <div class="ps-2 pe-2">
                            <a href="index" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-3 mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none border-bottom">
                                <h3>Hosting</h3>
                            </a>    
                        </div> -->
                        <ul class="nav flex-column ps-2 pe-2">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="index" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none fw-500">
                                    <button class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500" id="navbar">
                                        Home
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <hr/>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                                    <button role="button" class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#my-services" aria-expanded="true" id="navbar">
                                        My Services
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                <div class="collapse" id="my-services">
                                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                        <li><a href="domain" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Domains</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="hosting" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Hosting</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="transfer" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Transfer</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <hr/>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                                    <button role="button" class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#my-profile" aria-expanded="true" id="navbar">
                                        My Profile
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                <div class="collapse" id="my-profile">
                                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                        <li><a href="accountdetails" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Account Details</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="changepassword" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Change Password</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="newsletter" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Newsletter</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <hr/>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                                    <button role="button" class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500 collapsed" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#billing" aria-expanded="true" id="navbar">
                                        Billing
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                                <div class="collapse" id="billing">
                                    <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                        <li><a href="invoice" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Overview</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="paymentdetails" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Payment Details</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <hr/>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="status" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none fw-500 sb-active">
                                    <button class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500" id="navbar">
                                        Status
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <hr/>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="../" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none fw-500">
                                    <button class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500" id="navbar">
                                        Logout
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 ps-5 pe-5">
            <div class="container-lg">
                <h1>Status</h1>
                <nav style="--bs-breadcrumb-divider: url(&#34;data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.5 0L1 1.5 3.5 4 1 6.5 2.5 8l4-4-4-4z' fill='%236c757d'/%3E%3C/svg%3E&#34;);" aria-label="breadcrumb">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Status</li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            All Systems Operational
                        </div>
                        <span class="small">Last Updated on February 10th @ 10:43AM CEST</span>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="accordion">
                            <div class="accordion-item p-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <span>Servers</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 text-end">
                                        <span class="text-success">Operational</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-item p-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <span>Login</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 text-end">
                                        <span class="text-success">Operational</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="accordion-item p-4">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <span>Support</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 text-end">
                                        <span class="text-success">Operational</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasExample" aria-controls="offcanvasExample">
                          Button with data-bs-target
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="../public/js/script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code and following bootstrap docs v5.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/navbar/#offcanvas) here what i have done.so have look and hope you got your answer.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
            <nav class="navbar bg-body-tertiary navbar-expand-md">
                <div class="container-fluid flex-row flex-md-column">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
                        data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasNavbar"
                        aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel">
                        <div class="offcanvas-header">
                            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="offcanvas-body">
                            <ul class="nav flex-column flex-fill ps-2 pe-2">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="index" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none fw-500">
                                        <button
                                            class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500"
                                            id="navbar">
                                            Home
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                                        <button role="button"
                                            class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500 collapsed"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#my-services"
                                            aria-expanded="true" id="navbar">
                                            My Services
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="my-services">
                                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="domain"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Domains</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="hosting"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Hosting</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="transfer"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Transfer</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                                        <button role="button"
                                            class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500 collapsed"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#my-profile"
                                            aria-expanded="true" id="navbar">
                                            My Profile
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="my-profile">
                                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="accountdetails"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Account
                                                    Details</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="changepassword"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Change
                                                    Password</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="newsletter"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Newsletter</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <span class="dropdown-toggle">
                                        <button role="button"
                                            class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500 collapsed"
                                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#billing" aria-expanded="true"
                                            id="navbar">
                                            Billing
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="collapse" id="billing">
                                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="invoice"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Overview</a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="paymentdetails"
                                                    class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none">Payment
                                                    Details</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="status"
                                        class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none fw-500 sb-active">
                                        <button
                                            class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500"
                                            id="navbar">
                                            Status
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <hr />
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="../" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none fw-500">
                                        <button
                                            class="d-inline-flex align-items-middle text-decoration-none border-0 fw-500"
                                            id="navbar">
                                            Logout
                                        </button>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And add following css to your styles sheet

```
  @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-expand-md .offcanvas {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
    }
```

It is just sidebar navigation using offcanvas so you need to work on height and width of sidebar as well as content as you can see that sidebar take height as much as nav-link margin and padding computed.Hope you got your answer :)

Comment: The code above works really smooth on smaller screens, but whenever the screen gets larger, the navigation gets smaller and when I add a height of 100% it gets a little broken. Do you maybe know what I have to do in order to function normally as in my example above?

https://imgur.com/a/DQ4ofOM

Comment: Then in that case you need to set the height and width of sidebar navigation instead of using grid layout replace it with flex box.